# Exactness of $\Gamma^\infty$ Functor

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, noncommutative-geometry

Does anybody know a reference for fact that the Functor $\Gamma^\infty$, assigning to every smooth vector bundle $\mathcal{E}\to M$ the $C^\infty(M)$-module $\Gamma^\infty(\mathcal{E})$ of smooth sections in $\mathcal{E}$, is exact?

**Edit**: to be more precise, we are considering the category of smooth vector bundles of finite rank over a fixed, smooth, finite-dimensional and second-countable base manifold $M$. A morphism $F:\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{F}$ is a smooth, fiberwise linear map $F$ between the total spaces of $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$, such that $\pi^\mathcal{F}\circ F=\pi^\mathcal{E}$. Applying $\Gamma^\infty$ then gives the $C^\infty$-linear map $$\Gamma^\infty F:\Gamma^\infty(\mathcal{E})\ni s\mapsto F\circ s\in\Gamma^\infty(\mathcal{F}).$$

Comment: Where does the difficulty show up in proving this?

Comment: See, the point is that I cannot spend the time and space to prove it myself at the moment.

Comment: (By the way, you should probably be more specific about what category of vector bundles you have in mind —the morphisms, specifically— for clarity in your question)

Comment: This is part of the theorem of Serre–Swan. Googling for that gives as predicted a Wikipedia page on the subject which includes a reference to a recent work giving the details and a referenc to the extension to non-compact manifolds. I'd look there first.